# Android Studio Download constraint-layout fails

Tags: android, maven, ubuntu, android-constraintlayout

I updated Android Studio to 2.1.2 and I want to download `constraint-layout` tool but it throws this message

> To install:
>   - com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.0-alpha3 (extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-alpha3)
>   - com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha3 (extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-alpha3)
>
> Installing
>   com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.0-alpha3
>   Maven package paths must start with m2repository Failed to install
>   com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.0-alpha3!
>
> Installing
>   com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha3 Maven
>   package paths must start with m2repository Failed to install
>   com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha3!
>
> Failed packages:
>   - com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.0-alpha3 (extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-alpha3)
>   - com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha3 (extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-alpha3)

Does anybody else having the same problem with me? And if yes, how did you solved it?

**EDIT**

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Not sure about Maven, but you may need to update the Android SDK and, for Gradle, at least, use the 2.2.0 version of the Gradle plugin. So, essentially, constraint-layout isn't part of the 2.1.2 release

Comment: meet the same problem ,and my android studio is 2.2.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dear constraint layout is the part of 2.2, u can install 2.2 preview, it is available on site.you can also wait for 2.2 an

Comment: pfff..I download the Android Studio from an old bookmark...Sorry for the dump question

Comment: @VassilisPallas  its ok dear